# Looping through a csv file to insert data to MySQL using php mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

OK I'll start with my code:

```
include('connect.php');

// Prepared statement, prepare
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO funddata(ticker, priceDate, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

//Bind the parameters to the query
$csvData = array("","",""); //Initialise the $csvData array
$priceDate = date($csvData[1]);
$stmt -> bind_param("ssd", $csvData[0], $priceDate, $csvData[2]);

$file_handle = fopen($csvfile, "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

        $csvData = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        $priceDate = date($csvData[1]);

        echo $csvData[0] . "; " . $priceDate . "; ". $csvData[2] . "<br/>";

        //Run the insert statement
        $stmt->execute();

}

fclose($file_handle);
```

This fails to insert the data into the database table, although it does result in a load of blank rows being inserted.

The csv data is being correctly read as evidenced by the `echo`ing of it inside the loop.
Where have I gone wrong here?

Comment: try binding_param in the while boucle

Comment: just asking: Why don't you use LOAD DATA from mySQL?

Comment: @Luc I am very unfamilier with the syntax and this is part of a wider project where this script might need to be adapted for other purposes

Comment: @Nagasaki that worked but I the date was not correctly inserting - just a 0 date resulted. What is the best way to bind a date to the query?

Comment: i think you bind well, but maybe your date format is wrong, try to format your string date like "YYYYMMDD" or another default format "DD-MMM-YYYY"

Comment: seems I was using the `date` function incorrectly. This made it work: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($csvData[1]))`